# Spring 2.8 Session Management for Rest webservice

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am developing a single page application in AngularJS. The  backend uses Spring2.8. The application communicates with backend via Rest.

I want to implement session management in my application. The idea is to create a unique token for each user and check it in every request.

Is there any way to do with spring2.8 without any database access.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement spring security and define roles for each user.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//

Comment: Thanks for the response .The spring version used in the above link is 4.0. But i use spring 2.8. Is there any way to do it in 2.8?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html.